# Как создать генератор токена из данных по определённому шаблону

Tags: php

Есть входные данные типа логин, пароль и т.д. 
Нужно генерировать строку в которой будут зашифрованы эти данные, что-то наподобие access_token у VK, чтобы можно было потом расшифровывать их по специальному шаблону.

Comment: Самое простое - md5($login.$email.$some_variables), однако нужно еще передавать идентификатор (id) пользователя, дабы было с чем сравнивать.

Comment: Так а как потом его расшифровывать? Без сравнивания, что-то наподобие AES

Comment: Никак, вы просто при получении данных, берете пользователя (находите по email, например) и шифруете его данные по новой, если строки совпадают, значит это он

Comment: Ясно, спасибо огромное